# Can anyone help me understand what might be causing this error and how I can resolve it?

Tags: flutter

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' line: 1343
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

flutter build apk --debug --verbose

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions mentioned in the error message? Getting a stack trace or more log output would help narrow this down a lot.